# How can I get top users in specific tags?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a function like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `user_top_tags`(`user_id` INT, `tags_num` TINYINT(1)) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8mb4
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE  top_tags varchar(50);

    SELECT substring_index(group_concat(x.name  ORDER BY x.tag_score DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', tags_num) INTO top_tags
    FROM (
        SELECT t.name, sum(r.score) AS tag_score
        FROM reputations r
        JOIN qanda_tags qt ON qt.qanda_id = r.question_id
        JOIN tags t ON t.id = qt.tag_id
        WHERE r.owner_id = user_id
        GROUP BY t.name
    ) x;

    RETURN top_tags;
END
```

And I call it like this:

```
SELECT u.name, user_top_tags(u.id, 3) FROM users u WHERE 1;
```

And it returns a list of users with their top three tags. Something like this:

```
+--------+-----------------+
| Jack   | php,oop,mysql   |
| Martin | css,js,html     |
| Peter  | jquery,js,react |
+--------+-----------------+
```

Now I want to get the users which has active in specific tags. Something like [top users page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers) in SO *(which is for `javascript` tag, but I want to get list of users in multiple tags, like `IN ('css','html')`)*.

Now should I do a join on the query? Or should I modify the function? Does anybody have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Post your table structure.

Comment: `JOIN tags t ON t.id = qt.tag_id AND t.name IN ('tag1', 'tag2', ...)` will most probably do what you intend to.

Comment: @joanolo Well I guess I need two joins. Since `qt` isn't available out of the function.

Comment: Possibly you can add an extra parameter to the function...

Comment: @joanolo You mean, the join you wore in the comments above should be added into the function?

Comment: It's already in the function, but you have one less condition in it. Whenever you JOIN you can restricts which rows are joined any way you see fit. You're not obliged to always JOIN a.id = b.id, you can JOIN a.id = b.id AND a.col = 32, for instance.

Comment: @joanolo I see, sounds you're right. Just one question, is it possible to I add a *optional condition*? I can pass tags' name to the function, but sometime that function should do that for all tags name. Is it possible to I make this part optional? `AND t.name IN ('tag1', 'tag2', ...)`

Comment: AFAIK, not in MySQL. Write two different functions.

Comment: @joanolo There is just one problem. In this case, always the result is a list of **all** users, While I want to select just the ones that have an activity in those specific tags. Is there any solution to restrict users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume these are the settings for the problem. These will be the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
) ;

CREATE TABLE tags
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100)
) ;

CREATE TABLE qanda_tags
(
    question_id INTEGER,
    tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tags(id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE reputations
(
    owner_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id),
    question_id INTEGER,
    score INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ;
```

And these are the values stored on the different tables:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id) 
VALUES (1), (2) ;

INSERT INTO tags 
    (id, name)
VALUES
    (1, 'MySQL'),
    (2, 'PostgreSQL'),
    (3, 'MS SQL Server'),
    (4, 'Informix'),
    (5, 'MongoDB'),
    (6, 'CouchDB'),
    (7, 'Oracle'),
    (8, 'DB2'),
    (9, 'Sybase') ;

INSERT INTO qanda_tags
    (question_id, tag_id)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 4),
    (2, 5),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 4);

INSERT INTO reputations
    (owner_id, question_id, score)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 3),
    (2, 2, 5),
    (1, 3, 8) ;
```

At this point, we could run this query...

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    reputations r
    JOIN qanda_tags qt 
        ON qt.question_id = r.question_id
    JOIN tags t 
        ON t.id = qt.tag_id ;
```

and get

```
owner_id | question_id | score | question_id | tag_id | id | name      
-------: | ----------: | ----: | ----------: | -----: | -: | :---------
       1 |           1 |     3 |           1 |      1 |  1 | MySQL     
       1 |           1 |     3 |           1 |      2 |  2 | PostgreSQL
       2 |           2 |     5 |           2 |      4 |  4 | Informix  
       2 |           2 |     5 |           2 |      5 |  5 | MongoDB   
       1 |           3 |     8 |           3 |      1 |  1 | MySQL     
       1 |           3 |     8 |           3 |      2 |  2 | PostgreSQL
       1 |           3 |     8 |           3 |      4 |  4 | Informix
```

Your original function (slightly modified so it is no actually a function and can be played on at dbfiddle, and with some extra info), would do the following:

(these would be your function parameters)

```
SET @user_id = 1 ;
SET @tags_num = 4 ;

SELECT 
    substring_index(
        group_concat(name_and_score ORDER BY x.tag_score DESC, x.name ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
        , ', '
        , @tags_num
    ) AS top_tags_from_user
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        t.name, 
        sum(r.score) AS tag_score,
        concat(t.name, ' (', sum(r.score), ')') AS name_and_score
    FROM 
        reputations r
        JOIN qanda_tags qt 
            ON qt.question_id = r.question_id
        JOIN tags t 
            ON t.id = qt.tag_id
    WHERE 
        r.owner_id = @user_id
    GROUP BY 
        t.name
    ) AS x ;
```

```
| top_tags_from_user                        |
| :---------------------------------------- |
| MySQL (11), PostgreSQL (11), Informix (8) |
```

If you want to limit the tags that are checked, you can change the previous code just slightly:

```
SET @user_id = 1 ;
SET @tags_num = 4 ;
SET @tags_list = 'MySQL,Informix' ; 

SELECT 
    substring_index(
        group_concat(name_and_score ORDER BY x.tag_score DESC, x.name ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
        , ', '
        , @tags_num
    ) AS top_tags_from_user
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        t.name, 
        sum(r.score) AS tag_score,
        concat(t.name, ' (', sum(r.score), ')') AS name_and_score
    FROM 
        reputations r
        JOIN qanda_tags qt 
            ON qt.question_id = r.question_id
        JOIN tags t 
            ON t.id = qt.tag_id
               /* This is just what you need to add */
               AND (@tags_list IS NULL OR find_in_set(t.name, @tags_list))
    WHERE 
        r.owner_id = @user_id
    GROUP BY 
        t.name
    ) AS x ;
```

That will now return:

```
| top_tags_from_user       |
| :----------------------- |
| MySQL (11), Informix (8) |
```

The previous code will also work and choose *all tags* if you set `@tags_list` to NULL. In that case, the `@tags_list IS NULL` is true, and the JOIN condition is equivalent to the original case.

You can check everything at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=04974b8489dad479cccb1b0a0760b8d4)*